# Unable to use Blender with OpenShot in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: blender, openshot

I am using Ubuntu 16.04, and I installed Blender, and put the path in OpenShot->Preferences. I am getting the following error:

Blender, the free open source 3D content creation suite is required for this action (http://www.blender.org).

Please check the preferences in OpenShot and be sure the Blender executable is correct.  This setting should be the path of the 'blender' executable on your computer.  Also, please be sure that it is pointing to Blender version 2.62 or greater.

Blender Path:
/home/myname/blender-2.79/blender

Error Output:
No frame was found in the output from Blender

How do I correct and use it? I know that my path is correct because I dragged the file into terminal and it showed me the path, I also added the leading and trailing //es. Also, it is giving me an error output, "No frame was found in the output from blender", which it doesn't if the path is wrong. Also, the version of blender is 2.79.

Comment: @Nusry No, it isn't a duplicate, I have edited my question. Also, the solution given there doesn't work AT ALL for me! If I type the Terminal command there, it does literally NOTHING.

Comment: I don't have openshot running, but your error is that no output was found, that may be that the path was not writeable to you or doesn't exist so the result was unable to be saved.